# websocket interrupted while angular2 project is loading on firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, websocket, angular

I've just started angular 2. I've done an angular2 sample as given in the https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

when I run the project in Firefox using

> npm start

command in terminal, the connection get disconnected after output showing once.Error showing like

```
The connection to ws://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=6YFGHWy7oD7T7qioAAAA was interrupted while the page was loading
```

Any idea about how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Could you add the code you use to initialize and register event handlers on your web socket? Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this couple of times, `browser-sync` gets confused sometimes (: Try to reload page few times, brsync should eventually catch up and connect. If not try restarting or terminating nodejs process'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you manage your web socket but you could consider using the following code. This idea is to wrap the web socket into an observable.

For this you could use a service like below. The `initializeWebSocket` will create a shared observable (hot) to wrap a `WebSocket` object.

```
export class WebSocketService {
  initializeWebSocket(url) {
    this.wsObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.ws = new WebSocket(url);

      this.ws.onopen = (e) => {
        (...)
      };

      this.ws.onclose = (e) => {
        if (e.wasClean) {
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error(e);
        }
      };

      this.ws.onerror = (e) => {
        observer.error(e);
      }

      this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        observer.next(JSON.parse(e.data));
      }

      return () => {
        this.ws.close();
      };
    }).share();
  }
}
```

You could add a `sendData` to send data on the web socket:

```
export class WebSocketService {
  (...)

  sendData(message) {
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  }
}
```

The last point is to make things a bit robust, i.e. filter received messages based on a criteria and implement retry when there is a disconnection. For this, you need to wrap our initial websocket observable into another one. This way we can support retries when the connection is lost and integrate filtering on criteria like the client identifier (in the sample the received data is JSON and contains a `sender` attribute).

```
export class WebSocketService {
  (...)

  createClientObservable(clientId) {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let subscription = this.wsObservable
        .filter((data) => data.sender!==clientId)
        .subscribe(observer);

      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };
    }).retryWhen((errors) => {
      return Observable.timer(3000);
    });
  }
}
```

You can see that deconnections are handled in this code using the retryWhen operator of observable.

Comment: Didn't you see "quickstart" in OP? :-D